# Convert array of colon separated key:value to keyed array

Tags: php, arrays

I have got the following array:

```
[
  "icon: fas fa-toolbox",
  "read-friendly: Mix Fixes"
]
```

I want to convert this to the following:

```
{
  "icon": "fas fa-toolbox",
  "read-friendly": "Mix Fixes"
}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Tried this so far, so got the keys, but they values are wrong:

```
$settings = collect(\array_slice($lines, 0, $blank))->map(static function ($value) {
    $value = explode(':', $value);
    return ['key' => trim($value[0]), 'value' => trim($value[1])];
});
$settings = $settings->keyBy('key');
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Sorry, forgot put that. Just added it

Comment: And what have you tried to resolve the problem? "The values are wrong" looks like something that could be fixed

Comment: Just to make sure I understood - you have an array which you want to turn into a structured JSON object?

Comment: @NicoHaase Well the values is an array that I used to key it by, ive not tried anything to get just the values as the only thing I can think of is to to another loop, but I feel like there is a cleaner way

Comment: @El_Vanja Basically, well, a structured array/JSON, same thing

Comment: Please share more details. What does not work with the given code? What have you tried to make it work? Also, the expected output does not look like an array after all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overthinking it. You can simplify this by just iterating over each line and putting it in a new array.

```
$lines = [
    "icon: fas fa-toolbox",
    "read-friendly: Mix Fixes"
];

$settings = [];

foreach($lines as $value) {
    $value = explode(':', $value);
    $settings[trim($value[0])]  = trim($value[1]);
}
```

Comment: Ah damn, yeah I was defiantly over-thinking it. That's so simple...

Answer (score 0):

@aynber beat me to it but posting mine as it removes the need for a separate array

```php
$myArray = [
  "icon: fas fa-toolbox",
  "read-friendly: Mix Fixes"
];

// Iterate over the array where $i is the index and $slice is the value
foreach($myArray as $i => $slice){
    // Explode the value by the delimiter ':'
    $exploded = explode(':', $slice);
    // Set the key as the first part of the exploded string and the value as the second
    // trim to remove the extra whitespace
    $myArray[$exploded[0]] = trim($exploded[1]);
    // Remove the original slice from the array
    unset($myArray[$i]);
}

var_export($myArray);
```

Results in

```
array (
  'icon' => 'fas fa-toolbox',
  'read-friendly' => 'Mix Fixes',
)
```